# How to create a scrollable container that doesn't clip its contents?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a horizontal card row for my website. The cards have a little transition where they lightly rotate and raise on hover, like so:

[image: hover animation]

I want to make the row scrollable on the horizontal axis to make it responsive, but after setting `overflow-x: auto;` on the container, I noticed that the cards now get clipped, making the hover effect look pretty bad.

[image: broken effect]

I've tried setting `overflow-y: visible;` on the container but it has no effect. Is there any way I can keep my cards from clipping but still leave the container scrollable?? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe add some padding to the parent element?
You might want to add the relevant code to your question

Comment: Add scrollbar-gutter: stable to the body element. The browser will allocate a small amount of space for the scroll bar and not clip the content.

Comment: where is your code? please share what you have tried in a snippet here. and will make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the elements in 2 divs. The first and inner will have a width(for horizontal scroll) that is greater than the viewport. And the second and outer div, will have a width, that is exactly the same as the viewport. The second div will then have the property `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden` and it should work.
Example:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: max-content;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

inner-wrapper {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
 }

cards {
 // what ever properties you want
}
```